# What is all that <!--render facet: 5:0--> thing in Lightning Pages about?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, dom

I know it's a "who cares" question, but somehow I care and I wanted to have this documented somewhere in the WWW :)

In Lightning Pages the whole DOM is full of `<!--render facet: 5:0-->` statements.
Not only standard UIs are affected, also my own components are full of these debugs. Why is that happening? can we get rid of those?

[image]

I mean nothing bad is happening, but it is weird and spamming the whole DOM. In a simple Table Component, it appears 655 times.

Is seems to appear whenever I use any aura rendering mechanism like `aura:if` or `aura:iteration` that does not affect the DOM.

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!false}">
    False
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!true}">
    True
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!false}">
    False
</aura:if>
```

Results in

```
<!--render facet: 4368:929;a-->
True
<!--render facet: 4367:929;a-->
```

Same for iteration

```
<aura:iteration items="[]" var="value">
    {!value}
</aura:iteration>
<aura:iteration items="[1]" var="value">
    {!value}
</aura:iteration>
```

Results in

```
<!--render facet: 4367:929;a-->
1
```

**So the main question is, can we avoid it or switch it of?**

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but from the behavior I would say that these commented tags are just references for when the component isn't rendered to the page. But then it makes little to no sense to have them not rendering when the content is rendered.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to get rid of this <!--render facet: ...--> statements. This is causing some issues with jQuery datatable plugin. Any ideas?

Comment: @luka3z no, sorry :(